# horizontally joining multiple dataframes in pyspark

Tags: join, indexing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to horizontally join multiple dataframes (with same number of records) in pyspark using monotonically_increasing_id(). However the results obtained have inflated number of records

```
for i in range(len(lst)+1):
    if i==0:
        df[i] = cust_mod.select('key')
        df[i+1] = df[i].withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())

    else:
        df_tmp = o[i-1].select(col("value").alias(obj_names[i-1]))
        df_tmp = df_tmp.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())

        df[i+1] = df[i].join(df_tmp, "idx", "outer")
```

Expected number of records in df[i+1]=~60m. Got : ~88m. It seems monotonically increasing id is not generating same numbers all the time. How can I resole this problem?

Other details:

```
cust_mod > dataframe, count- ~60m
o[i] - another set of dataframes, with length equal to cust_mod
lst - a list than has 49 components . So in total 49 loops
```

I tried using zipWithIndex():

```
for i in range(len(lst)+1):
    if i==0:
        df[i] = cust_mod.select('key')
        df[i+1] = df[i].rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF()

    else:
        df_tmp = o[i-1].select("value").rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF()
        df_tmp1 = df_tmp.select(col("_1").alias(obj_names[i-1]),col("_2"))

        df[i+1] = df[i].join(df_tmp1, "_2", "inner").drop(df_tmp1._2)
```

But it's way sloww. Like 50 times slow.

Comment: `monotonically_increasing_id()` returns increasing numbers but they are not guaranteed to be in any order. You will almost certainly not get the same numbers for 2 calls. You have a few options- easiest thing might be to covert to `rdd` and call `zipWithIndex()` on both, join them, and convert back to `DF`. Even better would be if you could define a join condition based on the values or how to order your rows.

Comment: zipWithIndex() seems to be slow. Any other alternatives?

Comment: monotonically_increasing_id() was way fast

Comment: It's fast yes, but it's also incorrect (those two points are related). Keep in mind that DataFrames (and rdds) are inherently *unordered*. The correct way to do this is to define the join condition- what about the the first row in `df` means it should correspond to the first row in `df_tmp1`? If the answer is the "order", then you're out of luck. You're other option could be to add a `row_number()` to each row, but that won't be fast either.

Comment: yes. first row of df corresponds to first row of df_tmp1. row_number requires some column for order by. I dont have such column